# Indentifying a JL chip marked 'EE4222-1BB'

Tags: audio, identification, bluetooth

I'm new to electronics and my Bluetooth speaker broke and I want to fix it. This is the chip I think I need to replace.

[image]

Can you help me identify this IC marked 'EE4222-1BB'?

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that this IC is dead? The manufacturer is https://www.zh-jieli.com/ but I can't find that specific IC.

Comment: Mass-produced items also commonly use custom or programmable parts.  So there may be no public datasheet.  Everything from car parts to industrial controls are using proprietary parts nowadays, making repair impossible.  And then the [Right To Repair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_repair) is born.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this exact chip has been asked about before here on EE. There is very a likely a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: @HansmitmFlammenwerfer Thank you for your response. After I Power it on, the IC's temperature is increase rapidly, so I think the IC is dead.

Comment: @HungNguyen Please note that this is a MCU. A MCU runs a program called firmware. The firmware is custom to this application. You can't just buy a new MCU to replace the old (presumably) broken one because it won't come with the right firmware. The speaker is essentially irreparable unless you find a donor part.

Comment: @nanash1 After two months, I've replace the chip (AC7911BB) and re-programming firmware for that chip. Everything is ok now.  I want to send big thank to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possibly a [JL (杰理芯片) AC7911BB](http://www.yunthinker.com/FileUpLoad/DownLoadInfosFile/638164013968380860.pdf) MCU. The datasheet doesn't say anything about markings, but from what I've seen on other JL ICs, the characters after the dash seem to match with the last characters of the part number. This is the only one I could find that ends with 1BB and is in a QFN48 package. That doesn't mean there can't be others though.

The pinout looks plausible as well. The crystal is connected to the oscillator pins, VDD pins have bypass caps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @nanash1. It saved my day.